# PHP recreate JSON objects from separated objects

Tags: php, json

I have the following JSON:

```
{
    "data": [{
        "item": "apple",
        "date": "17.1."
    }, {
        "item": "banana, kiwi",
        "date": "18.1."
    }]
}
```

As you can see in the second "item", there are two elements separated by comma. 
Now I need to create a new JSON from this. "item" containing commas have to be splitted and put in a new object containing the "date" from the original.
So it should be like this:

```
{
    "data": [{
        "item": "apple",
        "date": "17.1."
    }, {
        "item": "banana",
        "date": "18.1."
    }, {
        "item": "kiwi",
        "date": "18.1."
    }]
}
```

How can I achieve this output in PHP?

Comment: just loop through and explode on comma to produce new item for each part

Comment: @NigelRen Of course I converted my JSON to an array, but then I got stuck with creating new elements by splitting "item" up...

Comment: It would be useful to include the code you have so far.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Eddie's answer but maintaining the data structure, you can cast to `object`

```
<?php

$json = '{
    "data": [{
        "item": "apple",
        "date": "17.1."
    }, {
        "item": "banana, kiwi",
        "date": "18.1."
    }]
}';

$obj = json_decode($json);

$fruits = array();
foreach($obj->data as $fruit) {
    $items = explode(",", $fruit->item);
    foreach ($items as $item)
        $fruits[] = (object) ["item" => trim($item), "date" => $fruit->date];
}

$obj->data = $fruits;
print_r(json_encode($obj, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
```

the ouput being

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "item": "apple",
            "date": "17.1."
        },
        {
            "item": "banana",
            "date": "18.1."
        },
        {
            "item": "kiwi",
            "date": "18.1."
        }
    ]
}
```